# Are questions asking about what a particular segment of code does on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Suppose I'm reading through some open source project and I encounter a block of code that I just don't understand, despite going to documentation websites and utilizing Google search to piece it together. Could I post that block of code here and ask for help from the P. SE community?

Comment: Thank you for asking here in meta regarding your potential questions before asking them on main.  Sorry that both of your examples are off-topic for Programmers, but thanks for checking first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code questions may belong on [one of several sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in/129632#129632)

- Broken or incomplete code belongs on Stack Overflow
- Working code that you want feedback on belongs on Code Review
- Code does not belong on Programmers *unless* it is supporting your question: while this is a conceptual site, it *is* about programming after all. But a question dealing *only* with a block of code would be closed as off-topic. Think of it like this: if your question is a thesis paper, code is like references. They help, but a thesis full of only references is no good.

That being said, "help me understand this code" is generally off-topic everywhere. *Sometimes* those question will slide by on Stack Overflow, but *only* if there is a suspected bug or other code malfunction (i.e. does not work as expected). I would search Stack Overflow's meta site and maybe ask on their meta first to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

No, code snippet explanations are off-topic for the site.

I'm relatively certain StackOverflow doesn't accept those questions either, but I would search and check on meta.stackoverflow first.